# Runtime error 1004 Not able to lookup the column with the url link name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search for the column with the help of VBA in Microsoft XLS.

Here is my xlsx data

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|Column1 |Column2 |Column3 |Column4 |Column5 |Column6                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|Dataxxx |Olivier |  40    | 100    |  1163  | https://www.facebook.com/groups/xxx/permalink/1338777099605419/      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Dataxxx |Geovanny| 35     | 101    |  1147  |  https://www.facebook.com/groups/xxx/permalink/1338288259654303/      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Dataxxx |Julien  | 33     |  66    |  1200  | https://www.facebook.com/groups/xxx/permalink/1339487882867674/      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the code which I have tried:

```
Sub myMacro()

    Dim myLookupValue As String
    Dim myFirstColumn As Long
    Dim myLastColumn As Long
    Dim myColumnIndex As Long
    Dim myFirstRow As Long
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myVLookupResult As String

    Dim myTableArray As Range

    myLookupValue = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/xxx/permalink/1338777099605419/"
    myFirstColumn = 2
    myLastColumn = 6
    myColumnIndex = 5
    myFirstRow = 2
    myLastRow = 4

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set myTableArray = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), .Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn))
    End With

    myVLookupResult = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myLookupValue, myTableArray, myColumnIndex, False)

    MsgBox "My lookup value " & myLookupValue & " are "

End Sub
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What does `=VLOOKUP("https://www.facebook.com/groups/xxx/permalink/1338777099605419/", $B$2:$F$4, 6, FALSE)` output? Hint: your lookup table is 5 columns wide, and you're asking for a value in the 6th one.

Comment: I have checked by changing myColumnIndex to 5. But no luck

Comment: Is the formula valid? Did the error number change? `WorksheetFunction.Xxxxxx` functions will *raise* an error rather than *return* one - if the lookup yields `#N/A` then you need to handle the runtime error, or yield it to a `Variant` with `Application.VLookup` instead (and then use `If Not IsError(myLookupResult) Then` to avoid a type mismatch error when you later try to show the result in a msgbox).

Comment: Did the error number change? No. Same error. I can able to search for other column result successfully. But not the last column.

Comment: I tried with =VLOOKUP("https://www.facebook.com/groups/xxx/permalink/1338777099605419/",A2:F4,5,FALSE). But getting N/A as the output.

Comment: So, the lookup fails, and `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` is raising an error. Refer to [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696904/runtime-error-1004-not-able-to-lookup-the-column-with-the-url-link-name?noredirect=1#comment101839126_57696904)

Comment: Figured it out when I finally noticed the table at the top of your post - the lookup value needs to be in the leftmost column of the lookup range, and the lookup column needs to be the column that contains the result you're trying to get... you can't have both the lookup value and the lookup column be the URL column.

Comment: There are 2 issues here - firstly, your data isn't in the right order for a vlookup, so you need to use `index/match` instead (or just `.Find()` seeing as you're using VBA anyway...). Secondly, you use your variables to set your lookup range, but then you use the same variables to query that range. When you set the first column to `2 (B)` and then lookup using that variable you're now looking up the second column of your new range, which is actually column `C` in the original range, so you need to correct your indeces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Your lookup table has the lookup value in the wrong column. `VLOOKUP` requires the lookup value to exist in the **first** column of the lookup table, but you're looking for a url, which is the *last* column in your data.

How `VLOOKUP` works, is that you give it a lookup value (say, "dataxxxx"), tell it where it's going to find that value (say, that range of cells right there - the lookup value is in the left-most column, always), and then which column from the left you're pulling the lookup result from: if you want to *get* a URL, then the URL can't be your *lookup value*.

Original answer follows.

---

`myColumnIndex` can't match `myLastColumn`; you're v-looking-up one column beyond the lookup table, which starts in column `B` (`myFirstColumn = 2`).

```
myColumnIndex = myLastColumn - myFirstColumn + 1
```

Should fix it.

Note that if the lookup fails (i.e. returns `#N/A` on a worksheet) then `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` will *raise* a run-time error that you need to handle.

If a failing lookup isn't an exceptional situation, consider using the late-bound `Application.VLookup` equivalent, which will *return* the error instead:

```
Dim myVLookupResult As Variant ' <~ note the return type
myVLookupResult = Application.VLookup(myLookupValue, myTableArray, myColumnIndex, False)

If IsError(myVLookupResult) Then
     'vlookup returned #N/A 'string coercion would throw a type mismatch here
Else
     MsgBox myVLookupResult 'string coercion is safe/valid here
End If
```

Comment: @Unknown see edit - this *did* work. But you need to handle a failing lookup.

Comment: But in my xls, I do have the url string. It should be able to find the cell in the code. I lost in why it is not able to find the url.

Comment: Watch for leading/trailing spaces in particular. Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the data.